# How can I find a bug reported by the bug reporting tool?

Tags: launchpad, apport

I keep getting the "internal error" messages when suspending/resuming (and sometimes the system fails to suspend and acts weird), and whenever the error message pops up, I tell it to send an error report. It has been going on for months, so I want to find the reported error on launchpad to see what's going on with it. How can I find it there?

Comment: You can manually report a bug using [this manual](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs).

Answer (score 0):

1. **If** you have an account for Launchpad, then open the [Launchpad site](https://launchpad.net/) in your browser, login and click user name
2. After that, click the <kbd>Bugs</kbd> link and <kbd>All related bugs</kbd> on the right hand site

   [image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I don't have a Launchpad account yet. When I create it, how can I tell the bug reporting tool to use my Launchpad account? (I'm using xubuntu)

Comment: @Meeep I guess it will use it automatically.

Comment: Depending on your privacy settings, this might not make it to your launchpad account.  I've turned off all non-anonymous communication to Canonical and I don't see any of my `apport` stuff, although I *do* have a launchpad account.